# featured image metabox MU

Tags: multisite, post-thumbnails

I have a MU install, the admin for my main site (site.com) shows the Featured Image Meta Box, but the admin for the subsites (site.com/blog1) the F.I.M.B. is not shown or available in the screen options tab..

The sites run the same theme and with the same settings.
The sites both run a (the same) child theme, and the

`add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');`

is defined in the Parent theme (framework).

It's like the `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` only has effect on the main site in my network..

is this a known problem, or should I start to dig for bugs in mu setup?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer here:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-featured-image-metabox-in-mu

Quote:

> "On multisite, if you do not enable the IMAGE UPLOADS, under Network admin -> Settings, then .... well, that kind precludes having featured images. Tick that box. Save. Featured images show up on the screen options tab."